# difference between this.$root.$on and this.$root.$emit

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I don't understand when should this be used `this.$root.$on('text', this.method);},` and what is meant by `$root` and `$on`

also its difference with `this.$root.$emit` isn't clear for me

Comment: I recommend using a Store anyway, an event bus like that is usually not the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$root` is your vue app.
`$on` are your event listeners.
`$emit` is the event emitter method

so if you define `this.$root.$on('foo' (arg)=>console.log(arg))`
and then emit `this.$root.$emit('foo', 'emitted event foo')`

console will print `emitted event foo`

Comment: what does the first param do, in your case `foo`

Comment: It's adding an event listener for the event `foo`, which will be triggered when emitting `foo`. @chafch